# Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: unknown instruction: #

Tags: docker

Im new to docker and trying to learn it.
Im following this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#apppy

So I installed Docker on Windows.
Created 3 files, app.py, Dockefile and requirements.txt

My docker file looks like this

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

When I run it in powershell

```
docker build -t friendlybuild .
```

But as result it gives this:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: unknown instruction: #
```

Like it doesnt work

I have no idea why it doesnt work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved by removing the dockerfile and creating it with Notepad instead of Visual Code

Answer (score 42):

I forgot to have a whitespace in `ENTRYPOINT["java",`

It should be `ENTRYPOINT ["java",`

Comment: Same here, but for CMD command,  CMD["java", ... ]. Adding a whitespace resolved the parse error.

Answer (score 29):

I just tested the same and by default VSCode seems to save the Dockerfile with UTF-16 LE encoding.

Resaving the file as UTF-8 allowed docker build to run without error.

Answer (score 9):

I had an extra line break in my Dockerfile. Didn't even notice it until I read some of these comments and realized it could be a problem. Originally my file was:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /usr/src/Main
WORKDIR /usr/src/Main
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx700m","-classpath", ".:./resources/:./lib/*",
"org.spark.docker.demo.DockerMultilayerPerceptronClassifier"]
```

and the error I was seeing was:

```
$ docker build -t docker-classifier .                                                                                                                                         
Sending build context to Docker daemon  248.3MB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 5: unknown instruction: "ORG.SPARK.DOCKER.DEMO.DOCKERMULTILAYERPERCEPTRONCLASSIFIER"]
```

Took me a while to figure it out until I read some of these comments above and looked into the line formatting and realized "org.spark.docker.demo.DockerMultilayerPerceptronClassifier"] was on a line of it's own. Once I removed the line break before it everything worked fine. I assumed the parser would ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for this--it was almost exactly my problem!  It is misleading that Docker CAPITALIZES the erroneous line-wrapped word, which kind of threw me off the trail for a bit.

Answer (score 4):

When doing it from Windows, I had to make sure that I have line breaks in my `Dockerfile` configured for Linux (`LF`) and not for Windows (`CRLF`) when editing it from a text editor.

Comment: You may need a CRLF instead of LF at the end of the From... line otherwise you will get an error if there is something on the next line...

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud Platform in console project using nano the comand work for me 

1º-nano

2-

```
# The Dockerfile defines the image's environment
# Import Python runtime and set up working directory
FROM python:2.7-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install any necessary dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Open port 80 for serving the webpage
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

save the file...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when working on a React app setup on Docker.

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.143MB
>
> Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: unknown instruction: +#

**Here's how I solved it**

The issue was that I had another file named `Dockerfile` (capital case **D**) which had some instructions in it, and it was conflicting with the original `dockerfile` (lower case **d**) in my project root directory.

I fixed this by deleting the `Dockerfile` and running the command:

```
docker build t myapp:latest .
```

to build the docker image from the `dockerfile` instead.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks ! I also had a script called "dockerfile" (lowercase d) that was blowing everything up xD Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks! I had same issue. The problem is, if you keep any file named with 'Dockerfile'(capital case D). Even if its inside the  subdirectory or named with some extra characters. For me, there was another file named with 'Dockerfile_new' inside a subdirectory. I renamed other file starting with some other character like 'New_Dockerfile'  and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While running, appended some text in the start of the file. Removed those using vi in terminal and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i run docker compose in intellij idea, solved this by remove the number in docker parent folder name.

Answer (score -1):

For mac users who face this issue:

Just edit/create Dockerfile using Python IDLE and remove extension.