# Docker-compose postgresql integration

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and am trying to make a composed image consisting of services, nginx and postgresql database. I'm following the tutorial here : http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/how-to-use-docker-and-docker-compose-to-create-a-flask-application/

And have been successful up to adding postgresql where I'm having difficulties and questions.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version : '2'
services:
 web:
   restart: always
   build: ./home/admin/
   expose:
     - "8000"

 nginx:
   restart: always
   build: ./etc/nginx
   ports:
     - "80:80"
   volumes:
     - /www/static
   volumes_from:
     - web
   depends_on:
     - web

data:
   image: postgres:9.6
   volumes:
     - /var/lib/postgresql
   command: "true"

postgres:
   restart: always
   build: ./var/lib/postgresql
   volumes_from:
     - data
   ports:
     - "5432:5432"
```

I have included his docker generator script under /var/lib/postgresql but keep facing **ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 1: unknown instruction: IMPORT** when I run 'docker-compose build'.

If I leave in the 'data' section & remove the postgres section in my docker-compose.yml file, my containers seemingly run fine but I'm unsure if postgresql is properly running at all. I'm able to GET using curl but still - I'm unsure how to go about confirming postgres specifics to confirm a proper environment and would appreciate examples on this topic in particular.

I was also wondering if running my docker-compose containers then simply running a separate postgresql container could also function if provided the correct ports.

Thank you!

Comment: `yml` is all about indentation, you can't neglect it, nor in actual file, nor here.

Comment: When you say `build: ./var/lib/postgresql`, what's in the `Dockerfile` in that directory?  That's what's producing that error.

Comment: My local yml is indented - I'll update it here accordingly now.

Right - I copied the generator script from the tutorial but I'm assuming it's improper. That was also my reasoning for asking about if I can run it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of your `docker-compose.yml`:

- yaml format (see for instance [`codebeautify.org/yaml-validator`](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator))
- [eol or encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49088933/6309)
- [multi-line instructions](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/6237)