# Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: file with no instructions

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM node:6-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
RUN apk add -update tini
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install && npm cache clean
COPY . .
CMD [ "tini","--","node","./bin/www" ]
```

I am running this on Windows using a command

```
docker build -t testnode .
```

getting below error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  443.4kB
Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: file with no instructions.
```

There are no extra space in my file and Encoding is ANSI.

Comment: would this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088933/error-response-from-daemon-dockerfile-parse-error-line-1-unknown-instruction?

Comment: My error is different and even I tried those responses too but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -

```
FROM node:6-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
RUN apk add --update tini
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD [ "node", "./bin/www" ]
```

- ENTRYPOINT should be defined when using the container as an
  executable.
- CMD should be used as a way of defining default arguments
  for an ENTRYPOINT command or for executing an ad-hoc command in a
  container.

Here "node" and "./bin/www" are passed as arguments to the "/sbin/tini" executable.

Check out this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) for a detailed understanding of  `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

I believe you are taking Docker Mastery tutorial by Bret Fisher. Happy Learning!!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've been able to reproduce this error is to create a Dockerfile that only contains a comment:

```
$ echo '#' >df.comment

$ docker build -f df.comment .
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from df.comment                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 45B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: file with no instructions
```

Note that an empty image, without an entrypoint or cmd, will still build, so trying to fix that with those lines is going to send you the wrong way:

```
$ more df.scratch 
FROM scratch
LABEL image=scratch

$ docker build -f df.scratch .
[+] Building 0.3s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from df.scratch                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 76B                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                              0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:874d031dd4b7103a9f4159a2bc82c7d21e1885aa477150105d482b3e0462aa7e        0.0s
```

As for why your file isn't working, it's almost certainly something to do with the encoding of the file. From the CLI rather than the editor, try `cat Dockerfile` and you should see the file contents, with steps like `FROM` at the beginning of the lines. If the file appears to be corrupt or missing line feeds, then it's not saved in the correct format. Typically you would use utf-8, ascii should also work, with linefeeds set to the Linux format (LF, not CR-LF).